# How to fix this JSON for loop in AJAX?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Every time when I press the button the button doesn't disappear but it still outputs the contents from the JSON file I love that but when I keep pushing the button more and more. The same contents keeps generating on the page. So I just want the button to disappear when I press it and I want the JSON contents to show one time only.

[Photo of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tx2DB.gif)

**JSON File**

```
[
{
        "name": "Adam",
        "age": 21,
        "interest": ["food", "relaxing"]
    },

    {
        "name": "Bob",
        "age": 22,
        "interest": ["working out", "sleeping"]
    },

    {
        "name": "Cane",
        "age": 23,
        "interest": ["football", "vide games"]
    }
    ]
```

**The AJAX File**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="demo">
<button id="bg" type="button" onclick="x()">Change Content</button>
</div>

<script>
function x() {
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
var employees = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
for(var i=0;i<employees.length;i++){
    employee = employees[i];
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "<br>" + employee.name;
}
}
};
xhr.open("GET", "json_example_2.json", true);
xhr.send();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `the button doesn't disappear` why should it? You don't do anything to make it disappear

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the button just add this line above:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ""; // <- this line
var employees = ...;
```

This will clear the `innerHTML` before adding the employee names.

If you don't want to get rid of the button entirely, you can also hide it:

```
document.getElementById("bg").style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: Well I just realize that but shouldn't any thing that is in the div would had disappear and would had been replace with the JSON contents ?

Comment: Yes, that's why it's better to hide it. Even better would be to create a new `div` above the button and insert your JSON there, this way you keep the JSON and the controls separate.